# How to set all data come from a certain table to be sorted with date?

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

I created a model.edmx from my database, What i want to do it to make all records come from one of the table to be sorted by DateCreated field, is that possible from the designer or how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible. You must define `OrderBy` in linq-to-entities query.